# xCode UIView with UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uiview, xcode6

I'm trying to make an app that has a calendar that takes up about 2/3 of the visible screen, and then under it are events that correspond to the selected day.

Basically it will look something like this: [Calendar App](https://dribbble.com/shots/1878977-Calendar-Revision-For-iOS-App?list=users&offset=3)

Should I use a UIView for the calendar, and then a UITableView for the corresponding information?

Also, I want the entire page to scroll when users scroll through the events in the tableView (not just the information in the table view). Would I need to wrap the entire page in a scrollView to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a UIScrollView. You can simply hide the calendar (with animation) when the table view scrolls to a certain point.

Another simpler solution is to put your calendar in the first table view cell, so it would scroll along with your events. So this one just requires one UITableView that fills up the whole screen.

Comment: what do you think of me not using a UITableView, and making the events that appear under the calendar UIViews, and wrapping both the CalendarView, and the event views that appear below it in a UIScrollView? @christophr

Comment: That would be okay, however, it's more complicated that way and more memory consuming (i.e. you have 100 events that day). UITableView loads each of its cell to memory only when necessary.

Comment: But with UITableView wouldn't I have to reload the table every time somebody clicks on a new day (including the whole calendar)?

Comment: You can have the calendar on a different section (section 1), then your events on another section (section 2). If someone clicks on a new day, you can just reload the section for the events. `reloadSections(_:withRowAnimation:)`